# php FILE POST upload without save

Tags: php, file-upload

I am using a plain text file in a PhP script. 
Is there any way to process the file in the PhP script without saving it locally? Everywhere I see simply uploading a file and saving it. I just need to pull some names off of the file and be done with it.
I have everything else working if I use a local copy of the file, so saving it, then deleting it works. I was just wondering if there was a way to skip the saving a copy and just getting that information directly.

We upload the file here.

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file">Filename:</label><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and in the script working with a copy of the file saved locally, I simply use

```
$file = fopen($_FILES['file']['name'], "r");
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If its text file (assuming size is not that huge) usually you could read it by

```
$contents= file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
```

If you are not sure which type of upload it was, check the request method

```
if(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])=='post')
    $contents= file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
elseif(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])=='put')
    $contents= file_get_contents("php://input");
else
    $contents="";
```

Comment: The condition looks the same, I suppose 2nd time you meant strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])=='put'

Answer (score 4):

When the form is submitted, check the `$_FILES['input_name']['tmp_name']` property. This is the path to your file saved in a temporary `/tmp` system path. You can proceed reading the name using, say, `file_get_contents()` and then simply forget the file. System will take care of removing it.

---

Just to stand out of the other answers, you could theoretically read the file without even uploading it using JavaScript, see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/. Then submit only the data you need as part of AJAX request.

Answer (score 3):

The file has to be saved somewhere before reading in this case is the temporary directory; You can get the contents of the file from the temporary directory, then if you really need to you  delete. See the following code:

```
$file = file_get_contents($_FILES["ufiley"]["tmp_name"]);

unlink($_FILES["ufiley"]["tmp_name"]); 

//contents would be stored in $file
```

Comment: It is not necessary to `unlink()` the temp file AFAIK as PHP automatically does this when the script ends.

Comment: @George Yes it does. It's for clarity purposes.

Answer (score 1):

When you upload a file, before you save it locally it get's saved to a temporary file. The location of which can be accessed by:

```
$_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']
```

You can choose not to save the file and `fopen()` the temporary file, as long as you do this within the same script that recieves the `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

no it would have to be saved to be read afaik, my normally routine is the same as yours, upload, read and delete.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` which would be the temp file that was uploaded.  Once your script is done running, PHP should even clean up after itself and delete the temp file.