# CodeIgniter 3 get contents of file through form

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

When I upload a file, I want to read the contents of it instead of actually placing it somewhere on my server. **The file does not get uploaded to the server.**

My PHP:

```
public function uploadFile()
{
    $this->view->postFile($this->input->post("thefile"));
}

public function postFile($file)
{
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
}
```

But when I submit the form it says

```
Message: file_get_contents(myfile.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

And reading from other places it seems like you're supposed to use `file_get_contents` for this, so I'm confused. Any help?

Comment: Your PHP is on the server.  How can PHP read the contents of a file that does not even exist (not uploaded)?

Answer (score 1):

pass the actual file path+file name instead of just file  name

```
$acualFile = 'uploads/'.$file; # should set where acual file folder 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($acualFile), true);
```

Comment: I don't think you get it (or I misunderstood your answer) but the file does **not** get uploaded onto the server. I just want to read the contents of it and do nothing else with it.

Comment: where is that file placed in server ?

Comment: It is not placed on the server at all

Comment: so how you gonna use [**`file_get_contents`**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_get_contents.asp) without actual file  ??

Comment: I updated my question and title. So if I cant use `file_get_contents` what can I use then?

Comment: you cant read text in file without saving it in server, save it then delete it.. [check this as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101048/php-file-post-upload-without-save)

Comment: Indeed what you are asking is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

When you upload files they do not go on the post section. The server stores them on a global variable called [$FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php). If you just want to read the contents access its fields like bellow:

```
   $file_id = 'thefile';
   echo $_FILES[$file_id]['name'];
   echo $_FILES[$file_id]['type'];
   echo $_FILES[$file_id]['tmp_name'];
   echo $_FILES[$file_id]['error'];
   echo $_FILES[$file_id]['size'];
```

For a detailed explanation about each field above take a look on [POST method upload](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)